# on an unordered list, how do I restrict one list item from being selectable?

Tags: jquery-ui, html-lists, jquery-ui-selectable

A quick sketch of my situation is:

```
<ul id="selectable">
  <li class="table" id="header-row">
    <ul class="row">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="table">
    <ul class="row">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

How do I disable `li#header-row` from being selectable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the filter option to include (or with `:not`, exclude) options

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    filter: ":not(#header-row)"
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M7pmU/

Comment: for those of you following along, I actually used `filter: ".table:not('#header-row')"`